# Ошибка "TypeError: 'zip' object is not subscriptable"

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы

Задача - проверить матрицу 5х5 на наличие вертикальных и/или горизонтальных сплошных дорожек из Х

```
- - - - -
X X X X X
- - - - -
- - - - -
- - - - -
```

Начал реализовывать так, но не пойму почему появляется ошибка "TypeError: 'zip' object is not subscriptable"

```py
import random as rnd

#рандомно заполняю матрицу
def rnd_sym():
   x = rnd.randint(0, 1)
   if x==0:
      s="-"
   else:
      s="X"
   return s

matrix = []
for x in range(5):
   horizon_line = []
   for y in range(5):
      horizon_line.append(rnd_sym())
   matrix.append(horizon_line)

#вывожу матрицу на екран
for row in matrix:
   print(*row)

fullres=0
#создаю функцию проверки дорожки в строках
def check_row(matrix):
   way = 0
   for i in range(5):
      a=matrix[i].count('X')
      if a==5:
         way +=1
   return way

fullres += check_row(matrix)
print("")
print(fullres)
#транспонирую матрицу
matrix=zip(*matrix)
#на всякий случай печатаю матрицу
for row in matrix:
   print(*row)

fullres += check_row(matrix)

print("")
print(fullres)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
matrix = list(zip(*matrix))
```

В следующий раз указывайте текст ошибки полностью, включая строку, в которой она случилась.